# How to add Google Now On Tap in a ROM?

Tags: custom-roms, rom

I have ROM which doesn't have Now On Tap on Long Pressing Home Key. How can I add it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to set up Now On Tap in Google Now settings. After that you go to settings and find the "Buttons" section (usually on main settings screen or in rom tweaks section) and then for "long home button press" select "Open Google Now" or "Google Now On Tap" (whatever it is called there).